# Java 2d array formatting?

Tags: java

I there, I am having problems formatting this 2d array. I was thinking about doing system.out.printf, but every time I do something like maybe %2f or something like that it doesn't work.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t,i;
    int[][] table = new int[5][6];

    for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        for (i=0;i < 6; i++) {
            table[t][i] = (t*6)+i+1;
            System.out.print(table[t][i] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

```
This is the output:

1  2  3  4  5  6  
7  8  9  10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18  
19  20  21  22  23  24  
25  26  27  28  29  30
```

The output should have the spaces perfectly aligned like this : http://prntscr.com/6kn2pq

Comment: You could use `\t` if the numbers are not too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) like this:

```
System.out.format("%4d", table[t][i]);
```

The output then looks like this:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6
   7   8   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

Or if you prefer to have the numbers aligned to the left:

```
System.out.format("%-4d", table[t][i]);
```

Which results in this output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   
7   8   9   10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18  
19  20  21  22  23  24  
25  26  27  28  29  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`PrintStream#printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Basically, for each row, each column needs to be formated to allow for a minimum of two spaces...

```
System.printf("%2d", table[t][i])
```

The next problem comes from the fact that the proceeding columns need extra space inbetween them ;)

```
System.printf("%2d%4s", table[t][i], "")
```

Which can result in something like...

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6    
 7     8     9    10    11    12    
13    14    15    16    17    18    
19    20    21    22    23    24    
25    26    27    28    29    30
```

Comment: or just add the spaces in the format `...printf("%2d    ",...` not that harder to read (eventually easier if having more fields).

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Depends on your requirements, I find using `%4s` this way is easier to read in code, but that's me

Answer (score 0):

You should use `printf` instead of `print`

```
System.out.printf("%3d", table[t][i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take my handle

```
for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
  for (i=0;i < 6; i++) {
    table[t][i] = (t*6)+i+1;
    if (table[t][i] > 9)
      System.out.print(table[t][i] + " ");
    else
      System.out.print(table[t][i] + "  ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.