# Console output in a matrix format

Tags: java, file, tabular, printstream

```
public class dataarrange {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            PrintStream myconsole = new PrintStream(new File("D://out.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                double a = Math.sqrt(i);
                int b = 10 + 5;
                double c = Math.cos(i);
                myconsole.print(a);
                myconsole.print(b);
                myconsole.print(c);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In this programming code I generate a text file named `out` where I write down the output of `dataarrange class.` There is no error in code. As per code we get a,b,c for 10 times. I write down the value in a systematic way in the text file. The text file should look like a matrix which have 10 rows and 3 columns. But when I open the text file out.txt all data are in scatter way. They are written as a line not as a matrix format.

Desired output:

```
a    b    c

val1 val2 val3

val4 val5 val6

val7 val8 val9
```

So on...

But getting output `val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6`. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: `String.format` - Maybe something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225415/java-2d-array-formatting/29225491#29225491), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124041/how-do-i-use-printf-in-java-to-print-out-a-table/34124251#34124251)

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) - `println()` for skipping to next line, even better `printf(...)` to format and print (this is `String.format` together with `print`)

Comment: Do you need to align all the columns?  Or just print them with spaces in between?

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Class names should always begin with an upper case character and then camelCase. So `DataRange` instead.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15215326)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use the escape sequences  \n \t  but the above anwser with  formatted string should be preferred

package test;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class DataRange {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            PrintStream myconsole = new PrintStream(new File("out.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                double a = Math.sqrt(i);

                int b = 10 + 5;
                double c = Math.cos(i);
                System.out.print("\t" + a);
                myconsole.print("\t" + a);
                System.out.print("\t" + b);
                myconsole.print("\t" + b);
                System.out.print("\t" + c);
                myconsole.print("\t" + c);
                myconsole.print("\n");
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this in the for loop will align the columns:

```
 double a = Math.sqrt(i);
 int b=10+5;
 double c=Math.cos(i);
 myconsole.printf("%10f %10d %10f", a, b, c);
 myconsole.println();
```

Output:

```
  0.000000         15   1.000000
  1.000000         15   0.540302
  1.414214         15  -0.416147
  1.732051         15  -0.989992
  2.000000         15  -0.653644
  2.236068         15   0.283662
  2.449490         15   0.960170
  2.645751         15   0.753902
  2.828427         15  -0.145500
  3.000000         15  -0.911130
```

Comment: Why use separate call to `println` when you can just add `%n` to the end of the format string, i.e. `myconsole.printf("%10f %10d %10f%n", a, b, c);`?

Comment: Sure. Spacing columns in one statement and adding a newline at the end is slightly more readable for me. Using `%n` is more concise though.